# Is it legal in the UK to lie and provide fake documents to get past AML checks?

Tags: united-kingdom, fraud, finance, money-laundering

Over the last few years, I was a self-employed consultant working as a contractor for a foreign startup that was successful and compensated me generously, including with stock options that I exercised and profited from. As a result of this, I have in a fairly short space of time amassed a 7-figure sum of savings.

This income was earned entirely legally and honestly, and I have paid all taxes on it that I'm supposed to. I am an innocent, law-abiding person. However, I have quickly learned that this does not matter; AML checks as they are carried out in practice by companies in the UK frequently treat self-employment or foreign equity as inherently suspicious sources of income, simply because they don't have a script for how to verify those sources or what evidence to demand. For equity-related income, I get asked for documents that I have no ability to provide, like the "certified dividend certificates" that I am presumed to have been issued with each dividend I received (simply not a kind of document that exists in the jurisdiction of the company I worked for) or the company's accounts (not something companies in their jurisdiction are necessarily required to publish or provide to shareholders).

Already I have had one conveyancing solicitor refuse to take me on as a client and with another I had to spend about 16 hours of work over the course of weeks walking a paralegal meticulously through years of my business affairs and explaining to her what stock options are and how they work.

Now I have had a little over a million pounds of my money frozen at a financial institution through whom I had invested it, and once again I am required to somehow prove - likely to low-paid administrative staff who are following a script and don't really give a damn - that I have made my money honestly. Given that I have already learned that the truth, despite being innocent, may go down very badly, I fear the consequences of being honest.

I wonder if I should therefore simply lie and forge documents, exactly as I would do if I *were* in fact a criminal and had instead earned my millions selling heroin to toddlers. It would be straightforward enough to type up a fake employment contract with some big company, along with several years of fake payslips showing me being paid £50k per month by them, and fake bank statements corroborating the payments, and would likely put me at lower risk of being judged a criminal by the financial institution who hold my money than if I tell them the truth.

If I were to do this, would I be exposing myself to any additional legal risk? Would my actions constitute a tort or a crime?

The most obvious possibility to me was that this might constitute the crime of [forgery](https://www.cps.gov.uk/legal-guidance/forgery-and-counterfeiting) - but it seems it does not (despite obviously being forgery in the plain English sense of the word), since the *offence* of forgery requires that the forgery be used to induce a person to carry out an act *"to his own or any other person’s prejudice"*, and my proposed forgery doesn't harm anyone.

It's similarly not perjury (requires the lie be in a judicial proceeding), and I don't *think* it's [fraud by false representation](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/2) (requires dishonest intent to make a gain for myself, whereas I merely intend to dishonestly avert the loss of property that I have already *honestly* gained). After checking all those possibilities I ran out of ideas; I don't think I've ever heard of any other tort or crime that would be applicable to the lie I'm considering telling.

Am I missing something, or is it in fact legal for me to lie?

Comment: If a conveyancing solicitor refused to do business with you, it may be because you are trying to move your funds into property, but they are *required* to carry out diligence checks as to the source of your money. It might not in your view be 'illegal' money but they may consider it to be 'dodgy' money if you cannot do that. But if you start to lie about it that only make things worse, because you will be asked to provide the provenance of your funds. BTW fast money is rarely honestly obtained.

Comment: @WeatherVane I fail to see how lying about it could've resulted in a worse outcome than what actually occurred. As noted in the question, having an entirely honest and legal source of income and telling the truth about it did not spare me from the consequences of the law as companies implement it in practice; if your source of income doesn't fit into their flowchart, they presume you to be a criminal. Had I simply lied, I would probably have been fine.

Comment: Fraud Act s5(3) "Gain” includes a gain by keeping what one has, as well as a gain by getting what one does not have.

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think anyone here will advise you to lie. There is a rather unbelievable arrogance to your assertion that "low-paid administrative staff who are following a script and don't really give a damn".

Comment: @Lag Aha, interesting. I guess what I'm contemplating is fraud, then!

Comment: As for forgery and "prejudice", see s10(1)(c) Forgery and Counterfeiting Act 1981. If these are real circumstances then you should invest in legal/financial advice and your question is off-topic here.

Comment: What is an AML check? Anti-money laundering?

Comment: @ohwilleke yes, solicitors involved in house purchase are required to conduct such checks.

Answer (score 4):

As noted by [Lag](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/17893/lag) in the comments, this *is* in fact fraud by false representation.

The [statute](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/2) states:

> #### Fraud by false representation
>
> - (1) A person is in breach of this section if he—
>
>   - (a) dishonestly makes a false representation, and
>   - (b) intends, by making the representation—
>
>     - (i) to make a gain for himself or another, or
>       ...

In the question, I noted that I had read this section of the statute but concluded that this did not apply in my circumstances because I did not intend to make a gain - only to avert a loss. But Lag notes that "to make a gain" is [defined in the statute](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2006/35/section/5) to *include* averting a loss ("keeping what one has"):

> - 5 “Gain” and “loss”
>
>   - (1) The references to gain and loss in sections 2 to 4 are to be read in accordance with this section.
>   - ...
>   - (3) “Gain” includes a gain by keeping what one has, as well as a gain by getting what one does not have.

Since my proposed lie clearly meets the other requirements to be fraud by false representation (it is dishonest, and involves a false representation), it would indeed be fraud.

As *also* noted by Lag in the comments, it would be forgery too! In the question I noted that [Section 1 of the Forgery Act 1981](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/45/section/1) states that

> A person is guilty of forgery if he makes a false instrument, with the intention that he or another shall use it to induce somebody to accept it as genuine, and by reason of so accepting it to do or not to do some act to his own or any other person’s prejudice.”

and suggested that my proposed lie, being harmless, could not possibly be considered to be to any person's "prejudice" and therefore would not constitute forgery under this definition. But Lag notes that [section 10](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1981/45/section/10) defines "prejudice" in a way that disagrees with me:

> #### Meaning of “prejudice” and “induce”.
>
> - (1) Subject to subsections (2) and (4) below, for the purposes of this Part of this Act an act or omission intended to be induced is to a person’s prejudice if, and only if, it is one which, if it occurs—
>
>   - (a) ...; or
>   - (b) ...; or
>   - (c) will be the result of his having accepted a false instrument as genuine, or a copy of a false instrument as a copy of a genuine one, in connection with his performance of any duty.

Subsection (1)(c) here establishes that if you pass off a false instrument to someone who is acting "in connection with his performance of any duty", then that is *by definition* to that person's "prejudice". Since the people carrying out AML checks are doing so because it is their legal duty, providing any forged documents to them presumably *would* count as being to their "prejudice" and therefore amount to the crime of forgery.

In conclusion, what I'm contemplating is a criminal act after all, in multiple ways.